# Django Endless pagination

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-endless-pagination

I am using **Django-endless** pagination module.I have installed it using pip and define all necessary code in setting and templates.

It works fine but the pagination *right now working is divide the number of posts in no. of pages* like if I have total 10 posts then it will divide it in to 3 post per page , thus at the end of page it shows total no. pages which is 4.

But I do not want pagination in this way , **I want On scroll pagination** , means when ever user scroll down the page next posts are loaded via ajax.

Code:

```
{% scroll_paginate posts %}
   <code to display posts>
{% show_pages %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the relevant javascript?

```
                <script>
            $.endlessPaginate({
                paginateOnScroll: true,
                paginateOnScrollChunkSize: 3
            });             
            </script>
```